# Use modular define pattern in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, amdefine

I have some web app modules (which i treat as object classes), I would like to reuse them in react-native.

However **define** doesn't work. I tried **amdefine** but got nowhere with that. 
The error I get is *"define is undefined"*. Any ideas?

An example:

THE CALLER (index.ios.js):

```
var React = require('react-native');
var ExampleClass = require('./app/ExampleClass');
....
```

THE DEFINITION:

```
define('ExampleClass', [
    // imports
    'ParentClass',
    'ExampleImport',
    'ExampleImport2',
], function(ParentClass, ExampleImport, ExampleImport2) {

    /**
     * @class ExampleClass
     */
    var ExampleClass = ParentClass.extend('ExampleClass');

    ExampleClass.prototype.init = function() {
        ParentClass.prototype.init.call(this);
        var oExampleImport = new ExampleImport();
        oExampleImport.doStuff();
    };


    ExampleClass.prototype.doSomething = function(oData, oStatus) {
       .....
       var oExampleImport2 = new ExampleImport2();
       oExampleImport2.doMoreStuff();
    };

    return ExampleClass;
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code that tries to use this? And the error.

Comment: Updated the question with what you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

So after a little investigation, I have came up with a solution (which I still need to put in place: :p):

- Isolate the shared modules as generic node modules

  ```
  'use scrict';

  let Module2 = require('../app/modules/Module2');

  let Module = {};

  Module.prototype.init = function() {
     let m2 = new Module2();
     m2.doSomething();
  };

  module.exports = Module;
  ```

  I could make this more ES6 of course with a `class` structure etc.
- Use something like **browserify** or **webpack** to package the project:

  This would allow the web app to be able to use the shared modules (e.g. so it understands such code as `module.exports` and ES6 syntax).

  It would also behave like one big package.
- Only the views will be specific to the target platform (iOS, web browser):

  Each view class would just `require` the necessary sub-class.

Comments welcome. :)